Vue.js + Firebase: (TinyMCE: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then'))
My project uses Vue.js + Firebase
I'm trying to integrate TinyMCE5 (image upload) with firebase well it does upload and retrieves the url of the image but the problem is, it's not displaying or passing the image inside the TinyMCE. It gives me a pop up error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')'
<Editor v-model="blogContent"
  api-key="----"
  :init="{
    toolbar_mode: 'fix',
    plugins: 'anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image imagetools link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount code textcolor fullscreen',
    toolbar: 'undo redo fullscreen | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline | link image media table mergetags | forecolor align | checklist numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | code |removeformat',
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
      const blob = blobInfo.blob();
      console.log('Blob Filename', blobInfo.filename())
      const blogImagestoragePath = `images/blogImages/${blobInfo.filename()}`;
      const blogImagestorageRef  = storageRef(storage, blogImagestoragePath); 
      console.log('Storage Ref:', blogImagestorageRef);

      uploadBytes(blogImagestorageRef, blob)
        .then((snapshot) => {
          console.log('Getting Download Url', snapshot)
          return getDownloadURL(blogImagestorageRef);  // Use blogImagestorageRef directly
        })
        .then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log('Download URL:', downloadURL);
          if (downloadURL) {
            success(downloadURL);  // Insert image into TinyMCE
            console.log('Passed URL to TinyMCE:', downloadURL);
          } else {
            failure('Cannot put the image in TinyMCE');
          }
        })
    },
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    min_height: 500,
  }"
  output-format="html" skin='bootstrap' 
/>

I tried logging to check if the URL is being retrieve. Problem is it doesn't pass it inside TinyMCE

What is uploadBytes and why do you write code in a template? If it's a method then define prop in a script, you wouldn't have such problem when writing it the regular way

Tip: :init is too long, define it in the <script setup> will make it easier to debug
